# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I m building a swift application. I m trying to integrate Firebase Notification message. So I write all code as documentation, but if I try to start application after some seconds, I will have this strange error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281b9cdb0'

This is my CocoaPods file:

```
target 'appUser' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoidingSwift'
  pod 'ActiveLabel'
    pod 'HSAttachmentPicker'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.8.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'SDWebImage/WebP'
  pod 'SVProgressHUD'
  pod 'Cosmos'
  pod 'Gallery'
  pod 'Charts'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  # Pods for appUser

  #target 'appUserTests' do
  #  inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  #end

  #target 'appUserUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  #end

end
```

This is the code into AppDelegate.swift file

```
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    /*func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }*/
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
                     [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        USER_DEFAULT.set("mykey", forKey: IOS_TOKEN)
        notificationCenter.delegate = self
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().isAutoInitEnabled = true
        self.configureNotification()
        return true
      }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
    
    func configureNotification() {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
        }
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
            } else if let token = token {
                print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
                USER_DEFAULT.set(token, forKey: IOS_TOKEN)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
       // k.iosRegisterId = deviceTokenString
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        print("APNs device token: \(deviceTokenString)")
       // USER_DEFAULT.set(deviceTokenString, forKey: IOS_TOKEN)

    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("APNs registration failed: \(error)")
        
    }
    
    // MARK:-  Received Remote Notification
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
            print("main method - \(userInfo)")
      
        if let info = userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            //let alert1 = info["aps"]!["alert"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            let title = userInfo["gcm.notification.status"] as! String
            hanleNotification(info: info, strStatus: title, strFrom: "Front")
        }

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }


}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
      withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        print("willPresent \(userInfo)")

        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
      
        /*if let info = userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            let title = userInfo["google.c.a.c_l"] as! String
            hanleNotification(info: info, strStatus: title, strFrom: "Front")
        }*/
      completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
    }
    //metodo chiamata quando l'utente clicca sulla notifica
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        print("Did Recceive \(userInfo)")
        if let info = userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            //let alert1 = info["aps"]!["alert"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            //let title = userInfo["gcm.notification.data"]
            hanleNotification(info: info, strStatus: "titolo", strFrom: "Back")
        }
        //Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
      completionHandler()
    }
    
    
    
    /*func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
       fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
      completionHandler(.noData)
    }*/


    //MARK:GoViewCotroller
    func hanleNotification(info:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>,strStatus:String,strFrom:String) {
        
        let visibleVC = UIApplication.topViewController()
        //recupero i dati del messaggio
        var datiNascosti = info["gcm.notification.data"]
        //let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(datiNascosti)
        datiNascosti = datiNascosti?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "") as AnyObject
        datiNascosti = datiNascosti?.replacingOccurrences(of: "{", with: "") as AnyObject
        datiNascosti = datiNascosti?.replacingOccurrences(of: "}", with: "") as AnyObject
        let array:[String]? = datiNascosti?.components(separatedBy: [","])
        var contentOfPushMessage = [String: String]()
        for riga in array! {
            //ho ogni riga adesso effettuo lo split
            let rigaSlittata:[String]? = riga.components(separatedBy: [":"])
            if(rigaSlittata!.count > 1){
                contentOfPushMessage[rigaSlittata![0]] = rigaSlittata![1]
            }
        }
        print("ho creato il mio dizionario con i dati ottenuti")
        //se nel dizionario esiste la chiave status ed il valore = chat
        //devo aprire direttamente la chat con l'utente
        if contentOfPushMessage.keys.contains("status") {
          // contains key
            let status = contentOfPushMessage["status"]
            if(status == "chat"){
                //devo aprire la chat. Mi occorre anche l'id del utente
                let user_id = contentOfPushMessage["user_id"]
                let username = contentOfPushMessage["username"]
                //apro il mio ViewController
                guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }

                //let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboard", bundle: nil)
                let objVC = kStoryboardMain.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatVC") as! ChatVC
                objVC.receiverId = user_id!
                objVC.userName = username!
                
                let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: objVC)
                navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

                // you can assign your vc directly or push it in navigation stack as follows:
                window.rootViewController = navController
                window.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        } else {
          // does not contain key
        }
        
        if strStatus == "join_live_session" || strStatus == "exist_session" || strStatus == "join_request" {
//            if visibleVC is liveSessionVC {
//                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(NotificationCenterStruct.JOIN_SESSION), object: "", userInfo: nil)
//            } else {
//                //visibleVC?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
//            }
        }
        
    }


}
```

I attach also an image to display Xcode when app still crashed
[image]

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8536

Comment: Sorry but I don t understand how can I should to do to fixed my issue

Comment: Please provide some basic troubleshooting information. We don't want to have to guess at where your code is crashing. Add a breakpoint and step through your code line by line until it crashes. Please update your QUESTION on what line that occurs.